# Prove the existence of a matrix $C$ s.t. $C^3=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrix-equations, diagonalization

Suppose that $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix with real entries.
Show that there is a matrix $C$ with real entries such that $C^3 = A$.

Comment: Please try something. #1 If $A,C$ were scalars, how would you do it? #2 If $A$ was a diagonal matrix how would you do it? #3 If $A$ is diagonalisable how would you do it?

Comment: #2 Diagonal Matrix D with the third root of the eigenvalues along its diagonal#3 M^-1D^3M=A That however doesnt prove the existence of a matrix C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal.

You can find $E$ such that $D= E^3$.

Finally, write $C=PEP^{-1}$.